# softlayer api: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid): The price 1 GB (204925) is not valid for package (46)

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

## background

Use sl_product_order.placeOrder api to order a vsi. The region of USA including wdc4, sjc3, dla2 creating VSI are failed withing using the package46 to placeorder. The other regions can success create VSI by using package46.

## exception

SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid): The price 1 GB (204925) is not valid for package (46)

## related issues

At last month, I asked the other question about package ([Softlayer Api: Exception: Invalid data on the order for property: packageId. Package (835) requires a preset configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026092/softlayer-api-exception-invalid-data-on-the-order-for-property-packageid-pac)),

## question

Could you tell which package can be used for all softlayer region?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have isn't due to package, you need to use standard item prices if you want to want to order devices on any softlayer region.

I suggest to review references listed at bottom, but basically you need to use the method **SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices** with following object-filter to get standard prices:

```
objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"locationGroupId":{"operation":"is null"}}}
```

Following is an example using REST:

```
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/46/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"locationGroupId":{"operation":"is null"}}}
```

**References**

[Softlayer Evault Price Ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754098/softlayer-evault-price-ids/38754571#38754571)

[How to create a priceConflicts hash like on store package configure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36412305/how-to-create-a-priceconflicts-hash-like-on-store-package-configure/36413337#36413337)

[SoftLayer API: Price is not been adjusted based on the location for Netscaler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075674/softlayer-api-price-is-not-been-adjusted-based-on-the-location-for-netscaler/35097544#35097544)